# How does the constructors for cv::Point3f work?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

How do these codes work?

1. cv::Point3f pt{1};
2. cv::Point3f pt{3};
3. cv::Point3f pt{1, 2, 3};
4. std::vector<cv::Point3f> pts{1};
5. std::vector<cv::Point3f> pts{3};
6. std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f>> object_points{0};
7. std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f>> object_points{1};

These questions arise from my implementation of camera calibration. The camera calibration requires us to create the 2D image_points and the 3D object_points to be used in cv::calibrateCamera() for computing the reprojection error.

Hence, I create the `object_points` like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f>> object_points{1}; 

... // Fill in the object_points container with the "actual" corners in the chessboard. 

object_points.resize(image_points.size(), object_points[0]); // Copy the entries in object_points[0]` to fill in the outer container of `object_points
```

Comment: How do they work or what do they do? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: The difficulty here is less on understanding what `cv::Point3f` does and more on C++ mechanics where you're creating instances of `cv::Point3f`, vectors of them and vector of vectors of them.  I would recommend you look up how to construct and initialise vectors first, then when you come back to this it'll make sense.